# How does one transfer multiple text fields with the same name in JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am using JSP and have successfully used JavaScript to get upto 10 dynamic textboxes working. My problem is how do I take the textbox values and use them on the next page, as the dynamic textboxes have all the same name. How do I insert those textboxes values into Oracle?.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a JSP  setup like this...

```
<html>
   <form method="post" action="ProcessTextServlet">
      <input type="text" name="t1" />
      <input type="text" name="t1" />
      <input type="text" name="t1" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</html>
```

You could process those text-boxes in Servlet "ProcessTextServlet" like this...

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ProcessTextServlet extends HttpServlet {
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws     
    ServletException,IOException {

      String values[]=req.getParameterValues("t1");
      for(String value : values) {
         // Call appropriate class to handle insertion of data to Oracle
         // Access the values via "value"
      }
   }
}
```

Please take a look at http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html for excellent information on interacting properly with databases using JSP/Servlets.